# Antonym for “boilerplate” or “cookie-cutter”

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

Context:

> Your advice was so valuable because it went far beyond the cookie-cutter tips typical of coffee chats or quick phone calls.

Comment: Can you please show an example sentence *with* such an antonym, using, say XXX for the antonym?

Comment: The title of your post suggests that the ideomatic terms "cookie-cutter" and "boilerplate" have the same meaning. Could you please explain why you think that?

Comment: 'Incisive' mixes metaphors nicely.

Comment: cookie-cutter and boilerplate do not fit in the same pot. [buzzer]

Comment: "useful"  would do it.

Comment: Not fo this situation, but in negative context it can also be "special snowflake" (when boilerplate things are expected and desired).

Comment: You're already putting a positive spin on 'negative' words. "Your advice was [not] valuable because it [did not go] beyond..." - You don't need an antonym, just state the antithesis.

Answer (score 52):

While [lbf's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/515639/8339) is also good, I prefer **[bespoke](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bespoke)**:

> 1 a: CUSTOM-MADE // bespoke suit

I would argue that [bespoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bespoke) has the connotation of being particularly fancy, which draws a nice contrast to boilerplate or cookie-cutter.

I'm not sure if it's quite ideal for your situation, but here's how you could incorporate it:

> Your *bespoke* advice was so valuable because it went far beyond the cookie-cutter tips typical of coffee chats or quick phone calls.

Another option that works for this particular context is **[singular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/singular)**:

> 3: being out of the ordinary : UNUSUAL

Possible ways *singular* could be incorporated:

> Your *singular* advice was so valuable because it went far beyond the cookie-cutter tips typical of coffee chats or quick phone calls.
>
> Your advice was *singularly* valuable because it went far beyond the cookie-cutter tips typical of coffee chats or quick phone calls.

Comment: Bespoke is the word that first came to my mind. +1

Comment: Interestingly many sources have bespoke as a chiefly British word [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bespoke) [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bespoke) [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bespoke)

Comment: @Matt — If true, I say it's high time we Yanks claim it for ourselves. It's a little late for Columbus day, but I feel there's also a discovery meme in here somewhere.

Comment: This is not correct. boilerplate is text that is pre-written, as it were. It is not the opposite of

Comment: @Lambie — I agree that boilerplate is text that is pre-written. I don't understand your point. Bespoke text would be text that is made-to-order, which is the opposite of pre-written.

Comment: The two terms are not interchangeable. You post the question as if boilerplate and cookie cutter were similar or the same. They are unrelated to one another. Is that clear enough?

Comment: No instances of "bespoke advice" in google ngram.

Comment: @Lambie boilerplate and cookie-cutter are both terms commonly used to mean "the same". Bespoke means tailored, which is the opposite meaning.

Comment: @Suncat2000 They are not used in the same contexts. And "cookie-cutter tips typical of coffee chats" ain't great either.

Comment: @Lambie — I did not post the question. I do, however, know what boilerplate means — standardized text that might have places to insert things like names and titles — and cookie-cutter — items that are metaphorically all cut from the same mold. Both indicate items with great similarity, and thus both have similar implications to each other.

Comment: @mRotten — it's not a common phrase, which is why I wrote "I'm not sure if it's quite ideal for your situation" and then offered "singular" as another option that sounds better in this particular context.

Comment: Low frequency == not a common phrase. No frequency == not a phrase.

Comment: Didn’t mean to be curt, but that was my point - that it’s not a phrase.

Comment: @mRotten — https://www.bespoke-advice.com

Comment: @mRotten — https://www.netwealth.com/OurViews/2019/1/23/fact-vs-fiction-why-bespoke-advice-beats-bespoke-portfolios

Comment: @BenHocking Google hit counts: "bespoke advice": ~145,000 results, "irregardless": ~1,070,000 results. So "bespoke advice" is used ~7.5-fold less than "irregardless". Also, as I said, no ngram occurrences of "bespoke advice", but "irregardless": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irregardless&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cirregardless%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cirregardless%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @BenHocking I found another good one that's maybe a bit more fair because it's an incorrect *phrase*: "could care less". Google hits: 5,480,000 (so used ~38x more than "bespoke advice"); Google ngram for "could care less": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could+care+less&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20care%20less%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccould%20care%20less%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @mRotten — please re-read my comment from yesterday, right before you said, "No frequency == not a phrase".

Comment: @BenHocking Right, it’s 1/38th as legitimate as “could care less”.

Comment: Apparently “no frequency == not a phrase” means *any* frequency by *any* measurement == a 100% legitimate phrase. Yeah, sorry no. If *not* q implies *not* p, it doesn’t necessarily follow that q implies p.

Comment: @mRotten — I don't know why you'd use the phrase to mean that. Anyways, you're focusing on the wrong part of what I said (I.e., 'which is why I wrote "I'm not sure if it's quite ideal for your situation" and then offered "singular" as another option that sounds better in this particular context.')

Answer (score 13):

**[Specific](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specific)**

> (adj) 2a. restricted to a particular individual, situation, relation, or effect
>   (adj) 3. free from ambiguity

---

Which can be used in various ways, to show why you appreciated that advice:

> Thank you for giving me such specific advice.

*Meaning; thank you for giving me advice, that was directed at my individual situation, and for me personally.*

> I really appreciate your advice and how you give me specific solutions.

*As in; thank you for not just giving me generalizations; but giving me unambiguous steps to follow that I can use to solve my problem.*

Comment: Given the example, "specific" is the only answer that makes sense in context of "advice". "Cookie-cutter" or "boilerplate" advice is _generic_, so the antonym of that usage is _specific_.

Answer (score 12):

As in:

Your **custom** advice was valuable because it addressed my particular needs.

> made to the specifications of an individual customer

This sense of **custom** can also describe something that is made just the way you want it.

Comment: Your advice was so ... *custom*?!?

Comment: Also "purpose-built".

Comment: @vectory  edited

Comment: "Custom" is overwhelmingly used for things that are made.  We don't "make" advice, so it sounds weird to describe it as "custom advice".

Comment: can a plan be made ... if so it can be a customized plan.

Comment: @KrisW even "tailor-made" would be better for advice, because that is made for a person.

Comment: custom advice? [buzzer]

Comment: No instances of "custom advice" in google ngram.

Answer (score 11):

There's also [*tailor-made*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tailor-made):

> 1: made by a tailor or with a tailor's care and style
>
> 2: made or fitted especially to a particular use or purpose
>
> 3: factory made rather than hand-rolled

(With the second definition)

FYI - the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bespoke) for "Bespoke" has some good info on "tailor-made" vs "bespoke"

Answer (score 10):

**thoughtful** advice

> : characterized by careful reasoned thinking
>
> e.g. *a thoughtful essay*

[definition 1b at Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thoughtful)

or

**considered** advice

> : matured by extended deliberative thought
>
> e.g. *a considered opinion*

[definition 1 at M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considered)

Could also work: [sagacious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sagacious) and [insightful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insightful), but I more like "thoughtful" and "considered" to describe good or detailed advice.

Edit: All my suggestions have some non-zero [history of usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sagacious%20advice%2C%20thoughtful%20advice%2C%20considered%20advice%2C%20insightful%20advice&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csagacious%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthoughtful%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsidered%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsightful%20advice%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csagacious%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthoughtful%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsidered%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsightful%20advice%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 4):

My first thought after reading the title was "bespoke."

But I think context matters and *bespoke* may not be the best word to use for your example.

Bespoke connotes tailored clothes. The opposite of bespoke is "ready to wear." I've also seen bespoke used for other products beside clothes, but the usage seems to be about things hand made.

You example context is different. It's about communication. Written communication in the case of *boilerplate.*

I can send a boilerplate email, but for the opposite, sending a *bespoke* email doesn't seem like the right usage.

Maybe for personal communication the opposite of boilerplate is... personalized. The communication is specific *to the person.* "Thank you for your *personalized* advice. It was much more helpful that the *boilerplate* answer on the website FAQ."

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use [**unconventional**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconventional) here.

Cookie cutter means adhering to the norm. I don't know that I'd typically describe advice that way, but that's the term you requested a semantic opposite.  I'd personally use the term *conventional* like in *conventional wisdom*.

> Thank you for your unconventional advice!  It was much more helpful than the run-of-the-mill conventional wisdom I got from everyone else.

[**Outside the box**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box) also has currency here. It means that the thought process in question was unconventional or from a new perspective.

> Thank you for your outside the box perspective. It was far more helpful than the conventional advice I received elsewhere!

Answer (score 3):

**tailored**

from [*tailor* (v)](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/tailor):

> 1. make (clothes) to fit individual customers
> 2. make or adapt for a particular purpose or person

**targeted** is also fitting here

Comment: You need to cite what dictionary this comes from.

Comment: @Laurel Link added

Answer (score 1):

**Useful**

> 1 Able to be used for a practical purpose or in several ways.
>
> ‘aspirins are useful for headaches’
>
> 1.1 British informal Very able or competent in a particular area.
>   ‘He is a healthy sceptic to much paranormal activity, and would be a useful expert to have.’

Used in your original sentence:

> Your advice was so **useful** because it went far beyond the
>   cookie-cutter tips typical of coffee chats or quick phone calls.